# Calling Matlab function in python3.6 is ten times slower than runing the same function directly in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

My classmate and I are working on a program and I need to call the m. file he wrote to solve a equation.

However, I found out It is ten times slower to call Matlab functions in python than runing the same function directly in Matlab. Can I solve this problem?

The function in python is described as below:

```
engine = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
print('start_engine')
t_begin = time.time()
rod, s1, s2, s3 = engine.shape_sensing(1.96, 2.77, 1.45, nargout=4)
t_end = time.time()
t = t_end-t_begin
print(t)
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is a problem. Is the code taking 10 hours instead of 1 hour? That would be very surprising. Likely it takes 1 second instead of 1/10 second. There is a bit of overhead in transferring data to the MATLAB process and back. Also the first time you run a MATLAB function it takes longer than subsequent times, because it needs to be loaded and parsed. If this delay really is an issue, you can always run it in MATLAB directly, or you can translate the code to Python.

Comment: The delay is an issue because we want to achieve real-time interactivity in a GUI based on PyQt5 with some other functions. The program did delay about 1 seconds while running in python instead of Matlab, which slow down the fps of the GUI interface. 
In fact, his code is hard to translate to Python, which is the reason why we try to call Matlab in Python... Anyway, Thinks for your advice! Maybe I should consider the translation after all...

Comment: Yeah, if you want "immediate" feedback in your GUI, don't rely on the Python-MATLAB interface. Making a GUI in MATLAB is actually quite easy, I would go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the overhead for calling MATLAb from python and not doing it directly.

Maybe you could improve performance by using parquet, that's a format to exchange code between Python and Matlab. If you have large column-oriented data that makes the transfer more efficient. Check it out here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/parquet-files.html

You can also find information about this here: https://blogs.mathworks.com/racing-lounge/2020/09/14/using-matlab-and-python-together/
It's about using Python from MATLAB but the conversion format is the same